# ausschlafen oder sich ausschlafen

Tags: reflexive

Laut Duden kann das Verb sowohl reflexiv als auch nicht reflexiv sein:

> ausgeschlafen haben, sein
>
> auch ausschlafen + sich: ich muss mich endlich einmal ausschlafen

Ich möchte gerne wissen, ob man die Variante mit "sich" tatsächlich benutzt.
In meiner Muttersprache ist das ein Reflexivverb und es wäre für mich natürlich einfacher die Version mit "sich" zu verwenden. Andererseits, wenn das Verb als reflexiv für Muttersprachler schlecht klingt, würde ich versuchen, mich an die gängigere Variante zu gewöhnen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es geht beides.

> Ilona muss endlich mal ausschlafen.
>
> Ilona muss sich endlich mal ausschlafen.

Die Bedeutung ist in beiden Fällen dieselbe, da "ausschlafen" etwas ist, was man nur selbst tun kann. Beim Verb *ausruhen* ist es dasselbe. Weitere Beispiele fielen mir nicht ein.

Comment: Für mich als Österreicher klingt die erste Version (ohne "sich") ein bisschen ungewöhnlich, ich würde mich wundern, sowas im Gespräch mit Landsleuten zu hören, zumindest hier im Raum Wien. Korrekt ist aber beides.

Answer (score 1):

Für mich als Muttersprachler klingt beides gleichgut. Klingt beides nicht schlecht oder ungewohnt für mich.